# formatting in java (Russian Peasant Multiplication)

Tags: java, string, format

I want to format the russian peasant multiplication with this scheme: The problem is that its not working with bigger numbers.

```
47 * 42
-------
23   84
11  168
 5  336
 2  672
 1 1344
=======
   1974
```

But when I have bigger numbers my format does not match:

```
470 * 420
---------
235  840
117 1680
58 3360
29 6720
14 13440
 7 26880
 3 53760
 1 107520
=========
   197400
```

It should come out like this:

```
470 * 420
----------
235    840
117   1680
 58   3360
 29   6720
 14  13440
  7  26880
  3  53760
  1 107520
==========
   197400
```

Is their a way to format it for variable numbers? I currently have it hard coded with %2d and %4d?

This is my current code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int num1=47;
    int num2=42;
    int product=0;
    String testNum1 = "";
    String testNum2 = "";


    if(num1%2!=0)
        product=product+num2;

    System.out.println(num1 + " * "+num2);
    int printLength = String.valueOf(num1).length() + String.valueOf(num2).length() + 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < printLength; i++){
        System.out.print('-');
    }
    System.out.println();
    while(num1!=1)
    {
        num1=num1/2;
        num2=num2*2;

        int x = String.valueOf(num1).length();

        if(num1%2!=0)
            product=product+num2;

        testNum1 = String.format("%2d", num1);
        testNum2 = String.format("%4d", num2);
        System.out.println(testNum1 + " " + testNum2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<printLength; i++){
        System.out.print("=");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("   ");
    System.out.print(product);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`%2d` and `%4d` causing the problem as it is hardcoded. There are various ways you can achieve this pattern. Below, you can find the lazy one :P.

Also, you need to take care of the `-----` & `====` printings.

```
 //changes
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
int maxLength1 =0;
int maxLength2 =0;

while(num1!=1)
{
    num1=num1/2;
    num2=num2*2;

    int x = String.valueOf(num1).length();

    if(num1%2!=0)
        product=product+num2;


    String s1 = ""+num1;
    String s2 = ""+num2;
    list1.add(s1);
    list2.add(s2);
    maxLength1 = maxLength1>s1.length()?maxLength1:s1.length();  //getting the max length for both numbers
    maxLength2 = maxLength2>s2.length()?maxLength2:s2.length();

}


//main printing lines
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {

    //calculating and adding required spaces for both numbers.
    
    int firstSpace = maxLength1 - list1.get(i).length() ;
    String space1 = new String(new char[firstSpace]).replace('\0', ' ');
    
    int secondSpace = maxLength2 - list2.get(i).length() ;
    String space2 = new String(new char[secondSpace]).replace('\0', ' ');

    System.out.println(space1+list1.get(i)+" "+space2+list2.get(i));
}

//changed here for better visual representaion 
for (int i = 0; i<=(maxLength1+maxLength2) ; i++){
    System.out.print("=");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("   ");
System.out.print(product);
```

[online demo](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y5dk3zug)